# How do I combine all elements in an array using comma?

Tags: php, string, while-loop

I know this question has with out any doubt been asked a whole lot of times. I though can seem to find a solution. So forgive me if it's way to simple.

The question is how do access the end of a while loop.

E.g.

```
    while($countByMonth = mysql_fetch_array($countByMonthSet)) { 
            $c = $countByMonth["COUNT(id)"];
            echo $c . "," ; 
        }
```

How do I manage separate each value of the while loop by a comma but of course I don't want the comma at the end of the value.

In advance thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can:

1) Build a string, and remove the last character:

```
$c = '';
while ($countByMonth = mysql_fetch_array($countByMonthSet)) { 
    $c .= $countByMonth["COUNT(id)"] . ',';
}

$c = substr($c, 0, -1);
echo $c;
```

2) Build an array and use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$c = array();
while ($countByMonth = mysql_fetch_array($countByMonthSet)) { 
    $c[] = $countByMonth["COUNT(id)"];
}

echo implode(',', $c);
```

*Tip:* You can use aliases in your query, like: `SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM ...`. Then you can access it as `$countByMonth['count']`, which looks cleaner IMO.

Comment: Thanks alot I went for the implode method which works great. Thanks for the tip about aliases.

Comment: Update your tip: $countByMonth['count'] to $countByMounth['COUNT(id)'], either way great answer.

Answer (score 5):

The simple<sup>1</sup> solution:

```
$isFirst = true;
while($countByMonth = mysql_fetch_array($countByMonthSet)) { 
    $c = $countByMonth["COUNT(id)"];
    if ($isFirst) {
        $isFirst = false;
    } else {
        echo = ', ';
    }
    echo $c; 
}
```

Alternatively, you could `implode()` the values. Or - perhaps easier to read/understand/maintain - concatenate it all into a string and remove the last "`,`" (SO eats my whitespace; the string is comma-whitespace):

```
$list = '';
while($countByMonth = mysql_fetch_array($countByMonthSet)) { 
    $c = $countByMonth["COUNT(id)"];
    $list .= $c . ', '; 
}
echo substring($list, 0, -2); // Remove last ', '
```

(Several other answers propose the use of an accumulated array and then use `implode()`. From a performance perspective this method will be superior to string concatenation.)

<sup>1</sup> See comments.

Comment: How you are calling the first solution "simple" is beyond me.

Comment: @quantumSoup :) I guess you're right. It seemed to be very simple in my head ... and very verbose when I wrote it :-S

Comment: @quantumSoup Perhaps if I define "simple" as *with only little modifications to what you already had, but perhaps not what you would do if you had nothing to start from* :)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can do:

```
$arr = array();
while($countByMonth = mysql_fetch_array($countByMonthSet)) { 
   $arr[] = $countByMonth["COUNT(id)"];
}

echo implode(', ',$arr);
```

Comment: `$arr = $countByMonth["COUNT(id)"]` should be `$arr[] = ...`

Answer (score 2):

Or afterwards just trim it off with rtrim($c, ',')

Answer (score 0):

While I think the implode solution is probably best, in situations where you can't use implode, think of the basic algorithm differently. Rather than "how can I add a comma behind every element but the last?" ask yourself "how can I add a comma before every element but the first?"

```
$str = '';
$count = count( $array );
if( $count ) {
  $i = 0;
  $str = $array[$i];
  $i++;
  while( i < $count ) {
    $str .= ','.$array[$i];
    $i++;
  }
}
```

If you "shift" the first element, then you can use a foreach loop:

```
$str = '';
if( count( $array ) ) {
  $str = array_shift( $array );
  foreach( $array as $element ) {
    $str .= ', '.$element;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Ty this:

```
int count;//

while(i)
{
    count=i;
}
```